# Spring 3.2.5 form tag radioButtons behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Can we iterate a collection of objects in the form:radiobuttons in Spring 3.2.5?

For instance in the addEmployee.jsp,

```
<td><form:radiobuttons path="empDepartmentName" items="${departments}"/></td>
```

And the method which populate departments,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        populateDepartments(map);
        return "addEmployee";
    }

    private void populateDepartments(ModelMap map){
        List<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
        departments.add("Dept 1");
        departments.add("Dept 2");
        map.addAttribute("departments", departments);       

    }
```

**Can be departments be  `List<Department>`** and allow client to select a Department name from UI and map the selected department directly in the Employee entity **instead of going through a transient variable empDepartmentName** then fetch the Department from the selected department name and assign the Department object to Employeee and persist the Employee. Am i doing this correct way?

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @Transient
    private String empDepartmentName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing a transient class - to take the employee name, 
you can use a spring custom property editor to convert a string to a type.

Custom property editors can be used to convert strings to an object type.
So, on Employee class you can have a Department attribute and so no need for the empDepName transient field.

Here is a good tutorial - https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/spring-mvc-custom-property-editors/

Comment: thanks. but is there any other simple solution. i guess this is a quite frequent scenario for a web app?

Comment: yes, i have had this a few times. Ended up using a property editor myself.

Comment: did that help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use converters (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) like this:

```
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter<String, Category> {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Override
    public Category convert(String id)
    {
        return categoryService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

and in servlet-config:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.app.converters.CategoryConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

i usually use it with form:select:

```
<form:select path="department">
     <form:options items="${departmentList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```